# Bash script failing to call other script without error

Tags: bash, shell-script, init.d

I have a bash script that is called from an init.d script upon booting up. I am needing to do multiple reboots for this script so I am creating an intermediate file that is used to check whether the script should be working or not. My issue is, in the script that is called by an init.d script (kinda new to bash, so I am not sure if this is technically called a script) that "script" calls another script that does my actual work but it never gets ran and it doesn't produce an error. It is checkversion.sh arg1 arg2. I have piped the stderr output to a file that never gets an error. It does if I put in purposely bad file path. You can see that I have some output files used after the calling of the script and those get populated correctly so it is getting access. Am I missing something obvious?

Basic structure:
/etc/init.d/myupdate  calls /usr/bin/databases/runcheckversion.sh  which eventually calls /usr/bin/databases/checkversion.sh    but checkversion.sh never gets executed and no errors are outputted. Thinking it may have to do with a PATH specification?

/etc/init.d/myupdate code:

```
#! /bin/sh
### BEGIN INIT INFO
#Provides: myupdate
### END INIT INFO

PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

case "$1" in
    start)
         /usr/bin/databases/runcheckversionwithupdate.sh
         ;;
    stop|restart|reload)
         ;;
esac
```

/usr/bin/databases/runcheckversion.sh code:

```
#! /bin/sh

after_reboot()
{
   versionNumber=$(< /usr/bin/databases/afterreboot.txt);
   #This following command never executes and theres no error output
   sudo /usr/bin/databases/checkversion.sh $versionNumber /usr/bin/databases/my.db.sqlite 2> didntwork.txt 
  ((versionNumber++));
  echo $versionNumber>/usr/bin/databases/afterreboot.txt;  
}




if [ -f /usr/bin/databases/afterreboot.txt ]; then
    sleep 20
    after_reboot
    checkVersion=$(< /usr/bin/databases/afterreboot.txt)
    if(($checkVersion < 2)); then
    sudo reboot
    fi
    echo "DONE"
else
  echo "1">/usr/bin/afterreboot.txt;
  echo "worked"
  sudo reboot
fi
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file you are checking for the presence of before calling the after_reboot() function is: /usr/bin/databases/afterreboot.txt

However the file you are echoing 1 into (if above file doesn't exist) is: /usr/bin/afterreboot.txt

So it looks like you're creating one file (in /usr/bin) and checking for another (in /usr/bin/databases).

The following may work:

```
#! /bin/sh

after_reboot()
{
   versionNumber=$(< /usr/bin/databases/afterreboot.txt);
   #This following command never executes and theres no error output
   sudo /usr/bin/databases/checkversion.sh $versionNumber /usr/bin/databases/my.db.sqlite 2> didntwork.txt 
  ((versionNumber++));
  echo $versionNumber>/usr/bin/databases/afterreboot.txt;  
}




if [ -f /usr/bin/databases/afterreboot.txt ]; then
    sleep 20
    after_reboot
    checkVersion=$(< /usr/bin/databases/afterreboot.txt)
    if(($checkVersion < 2)); then
    sudo reboot
    fi
    echo "DONE"
else
  echo "1">/usr/bin/databases/afterreboot.txt;
  echo "worked"
  sudo reboot
fi
```